# How to evaluate Ext of $M/IM$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Suppose that $I \subset R$ is an ideal generated by an $R$-regular sequence $\mathbf t = (t_1, \dots, t_r)$ (not necessarily $M$-regular). I am wondering what techniques are out there that allow to find $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_{R/I}(M/IM,R/I)$. I am particularly interested in expressing it in terms of modules $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(M,R)$, if possible.

My own progress: Using base change spectral sequence I have found that $\mathrm{Ext}^p_{R/I}(M/IM,R/I) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^{p+r}_R(M/IM,R)$. I like the right hand side more than the left hand side because it involves only $R$ (and not $R/I$). Moreover, modules $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(M/IM,R)$ fit together with $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(M,R)$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(IM,R)$ in a long exact sequence. In general I had little success in extracting information from this long exact sequence. The case of $r=1$ with $t_1$ being $M$-regular is simple. I suspect its analysis can be generalized to general $r$ if $\mathbf t$ is assumed to be $M$-regular. However, it is important for my application to allow $\mathbf t$ to be not $M$-regular.

Comment: What parameters did you use for the CRSS?

Comment: If $f : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, $A$ an $S$-module and $B$ an $R$-module, then there is a spectral sequence with $\mathrm E_2^{pq} = \mathrm{Ext}^p_S(A,\mathrm{Ext}^q_R(S,B)) \implies \mathrm{Ext}^{p+q}_R(A,B)$. I took $S=R/I$, $B=R$ and $A=M/IM$. This gives an easy spectral sequence because $\mathrm{Ext}^q(R/I,R)$ is $R/I$ for $q=r$ and zero in every other degree, thanks to the assumption that $\mathbf t$ is a regular sequence.